# fetch distinct and unique contacts from the phone avoiding duplicity

Tags: android, contactscontract

i want to retrieve the contact list from the phone avoiding any duplicates. i think it is retrieving the contacts from google account,phone or sim. so how to avoid the duplicate contacts. though a contact can have same number but with different numbers. but same name and same number should not appear in the list.
this is the code.

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
        };
        String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '"
                + ("1") + "'";
        //String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, selection
                + " AND " + ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER
                + "=1", null,  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");

        if(cur != null) {
            if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
                while (cur.moveToNext()) {

                    String contactPhone = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    String contactName = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String contactId = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
                    contacts.add(new Contact().setId(contactId).setName(contactName).setNumber(contactPhone));
                }
            }

            cur.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether it is reliable or not, but it worked for me

First copy the contacts in `ArrayMap` with phone numbers as key and contact name as value. In this method, even if the phone numbers are repeated, it will just update the name.

Once ArrayMap is createt, you can use iterator to retrieve the contact with unique phone number.

```
ArrayMap<String, String> arrayMap = new ArrayMap<>();
//
//
 while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                String phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                arrayMap.put(phone, name);
            }
//
//
for(String key: arrayMap.keySet()){
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsonObject.put("name", arrayMap.get(key));
                jsonObject.put("phone_number", key);
                contactsList.put(jsonObject);
            }catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

in your case you can directly call for `new Contacts(...)` instead of using JSONObject.

Answer (score 1):

Unique contact fetch and data load fast this solution is better

```
String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = '1'";
String order = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";
String[] projection = new String[] {
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY
};

void getAllContacts() {
    Cursor crContacts = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, order);
    String temp_name="";
    while (crContacts.moveToNext()) {
        FetchFamilymember temp = new FetchFamilymember();
        String name = crContacts.getString(crContacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String phone = crContacts.getString(crContacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        String photoUri = crContacts.getString(crContacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));

        if (name.equals(temp_name))
            continue;
        temp_name=name;
        temp.setName(name);
        temp.setPhone(phone);
        temp.setIsselect(false);
        familylist.add(temp);
        Log.d("readContacts: " , name + " Contactnumber" + phone);

    }
    crContacts.close();

}
```